# AVPlayerViewController's view as subview

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint, avplayerviewcontroller

I am trying to configure `AVPlayerViewController` this way:

In `- (void) willMoveToSuperview:(UIView *)newSuperview` I call this code:

```
if(self.moviePlayerController == nil) {

                self.moviePlayerController = [[AVPlayerViewController alloc] init];

                [self.view addSubview: [self.moviePlayerController view]];

                [self.view setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
                [self.moviePlayerController.view setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];

                NSDictionary *views = @{ @"selfview" : self.view, @"movieControllerView" : [self moviePlayerController].view};

                [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[movieControllerView]|"
                                                                                  options:0
                                                                                  metrics:nil
                                                                                    views:views]];
                [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[movieControllerView]|"
                                                                                  options:0
                                                                                  metrics:nil
                                                                                    views:views]];
            }
```

But when the player is created I get this exception:

```
Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
                Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want.
                Try this:
                (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect;
                (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it.
                (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints)
                (
                 "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x1499d1730 AVPlayerView:0x149885150.(null) == TSNView:0x14996bca0.(null) - 110>",
                 "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1498bf480 AVPlayerView:0x149885150.leading == TSNView:0x14996bca0.leading>",
                 "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1498bc800 UIView:0x14996bca0.trailing == AVPlayerView:0x149885150.trailing>"
                 )

                Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint
                <NSLayoutConstraint:0x1498bc800 UIView:0x14996bca0.trailing == AVPlayerView:0x149885150.trailing>
```

The code was working for `MPMoviePlayerController` without an issue. Is that a proper way how I can nest the `AVPlayerViewController's` view inside another view using auto layout?

Comment: When you look in XCode which objects you can drag into your storyboard: at the bottom you find a container view. That is a view that can contain a controller. Put your whole moviePlayerController inside that view, not just its view.

Comment: @GerdCastan I am using just the code, but I will try that. Thank you. Edit: I am using simple UIView where I need to place the controller, which is not possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The autoresizing mask is translated into constraints upon adding the view into the hierarchy. Therefore you should change the order of this:

```
[self.view addSubview: [self.moviePlayerController view]];
[self.view setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
[self.moviePlayerController.view setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
```

Into this:

```
[self.view setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
[self.moviePlayerController.view setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
[self.view addSubview: [self.moviePlayerController view]];
```

Also I hope you understand that [view controller containment](https://www.objc.io/issues/1-view-controllers/containment-view-controller/) is [more than just adding a view controller's `view` to your hierarchy](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ImplementingaContainerViewController.html).

Comment: This works, but I do not understand that. It should be processed after setNeedsLayout, or layoutIfNeeded.. and the order I expect should not make any difference. But it does. Thank you @Tamas.

Comment: @VladimírSlavík `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` creates actual `NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint`s and adds them to the superview. That's why it's futile to turn it off after the view has been added, because the constraints are already there.

Answer (score 0):

Apply programmatically constraint by using the[`KVConstraintExtensionsMaster`](https://github.com/keshavvishwkarma/KVConstraintExtensionsMaster) library.

```
 if( self.moviePlayerController == nil)
    {
        self.moviePlayerController = [[AVPlayerViewController alloc] init];
        [self.view addSubview: [self.moviePlayerController view]];  
        /* prepare moviePlayerController view for autolayout constraint */
        [self.moviePlayerController.view prepareViewForAutoLayout];
        /* apply constraint to fit superView (self.view) */
        [self.moviePlayerController.view applyConstraintFitToSuperview];
    }
```